# Returning distinct rows meeting condition

Tags: sql

I have a table in the format below (with sample data)

tblquotes
QuoteID / PetType 
123 / 16
123 / 16
123 / 17
456 / 14
789 / 15

How can I distinct rows where a PetType of 16 does not exist for a QuoteID? So my returned results would be :-

QuoteID 
456 
789

Comment: the answer is pretty much in the question. did you try that?

Comment: HINT:  `SELECT DISTINCT . . . WHERE`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL it is almost exactly what you say:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QuoteID, PetType 
FROM tblquotes
WHERE PetType = 16
```

So with the `DISTINCT` keyword you select *distinct* rows. And the `WHERE` clause is used to *filter* rows: only the ones where `PetType = 16` are allowed.

Comment: Distinct * isn't a sound suggestion. The columns shiuld be specified.

Comment: Nice code formatting, didn't know that was supported. Thanks.